# Can 'in' be omitted in the phrase "be employed in doing..."

Tags: phrase-usage

> Harry thought he'd be much better employed doing Snape's  punishment essay than sitting here trying to find meaning in a lot of made-up dreams.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

According to dictionaries, *be employed in doing* is a set. But I'm not sure if we could omit the word **in** here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding 'in' in there would rather be erroneous. "Harry thought he'd be much [busy] doing Snape's punishment essay than sitting here trying to find meaning in a lot of made-up dreams."

Comment: 'employed' in there is used as an adjective, and can be replaced with any other adjective like 'busy', an 'in' after that would be extraneous and ungrammatical.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli But I found this example in my dictionary: *Her days are employed in gardening and voluntary work.*

Comment: **Employed in** is a standard phrase although the preposition is frequently omitted, depending on the construction.

Comment: You could, and you could also include _by_.  Both are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a question of idiom and preference rather than grammar. Both of the following would be perfectly idiomatic.

> They are employed in doing the necessary research
>   They are employed in doing essential analysis

But equally:

> They are employed sweeping the paths
>   They are employed doing the dirty work

The use of **in** implies **in the business of**. This implication sounds more natural in some contexts than in others.